# Executing a script within a script also executes its echo statements

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a simple bash script, the script is taking a command from command line as an argument and executing that command(in my case another bash script).

The command can be anything, it can a plain `echo` statement or it can be a call to another script. For example: In below example I am calling my script like

`sh wrapper.sh "sh dummy.sh" \tmp\logs.txt`

```
> cat dummy.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "scooby dooby doo"
echo "duck tales whoo hoo"


> cat wrapper.sh
#!/bin/bash

commandToExec=$1
logPath=$2

{
echo "Executing command:  ${commandToExec}"
$(commandToExec)
ret_status=$?

if [ $ret_status -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "Script ran successfully"
  else
    echo "Script failed"
fi  

echo "Script status is ${ret_status}"
} >> ${logPath} 2>&1

echo "Return status for command $ret_status"
exit $ret_status
```

My output is :

```
Executing command:  sh dummy.sh
wrapper.sh: line 8: scooby: command not found
```

So although it executes `dummy.sh` successfully and should have returned a status `0` it executes the echo statement in `dummy.sh` and fails with non 0 exit code.

Comment: That's what `$()` does.  If you just want to execute your script, write `commandToExec`.  If you want to attempt to execute the output of the script as commands, write `$(commandToExec)`

Comment: You mean, use `$commandToExec` instead of `$($commandToExec)` -- @explorer, when you use the latter, you execute the command, *and then you execute the **output***.

Comment: Can you please copy-paste your scripts from your post into a new directory, run the command you post, and verify that the output is the same? The way it's posted you should be getting something like `wrapper.sh: 7: commandToExec: not found` rather than `wrapper.sh: line 8: scooby: command not found`

Comment: Also, I can see this happening in your future: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @glennjackman if I use $1 directly instead of putting that in variable then it should be fine, right?

Comment: WilliamPursell and glenn jackman thanks.

Comment: @thatotherguy if I copy the script to another directly it won't be able to find dummy.sh however the argument is actually /path/script rather that /script only.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could post actual code and actual output. It may seem like it shouldn't make a difference whether you post the actual code you're running or some code that is sorta-kinda in the same vein for illustration purposes, but programming is a precision game and single character changes make a huge difference.

Comment: @thatotherguy I agree, however the script exactly the same, that dummy script is a part of test case. I am trying to do both -ve and +ve test to figure out all the cases where my code breaks.

Comment: @Explorer Is the problem that you're accidentally running different scripts? `$(commandToExec)` should never result in `wrapper.sh: line 8: scooby: command not found`, even if `commandToExec="dummy.sh" or `commandToExec="scooby dooby doo"`. It will give `commandToExec: command not found` instead. If your script had `$($1)` then the solution would be trivial, but now nothing makes sense